# If $f(x)=\psi(\langle a,x \rangle )$, where $\psi:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \in C^{2}$, then every critical point of $f$ is degenerate.

Tags: real-analysis, multivalued-functions

If $f(x)=\psi(\langle a,x \rangle )$, where $\psi:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \in C^{2}$, then every critical point of $f$ is degenerate.
My aim here is to show that the determinant of Hessian matrix of $f$ will be 0 for every critical point of $f$. But to get there I suppose I need to find the second partial derivatives of $f$, and there is my problem. Derivating in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is very complicated to me, but I tried using the chain rule. Please verify my calculations.

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (\psi o \langle \rangle) (a,x) = \psi ' (\langle a,x \rangle).\langle \rangle'(a,x)  \Rightarrow \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}} f(x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} ( \psi'(\langle a,x \rangle)\langle \rangle'(a,x)) = \psi''(\langle a,x \rangle)\langle \rangle'(a,x)\langle \rangle'(a,x) + \psi'(\langle a,x \rangle)\langle \rangle''(a,x)$

But I can feel there is something wrong. Or is it right and should I calculate the other componentes of the Hessian?

Thanks.

Comment: what is a degenerate critical point?

Comment: anyway: $\nabla f(x) = \psi'(\langle a, x \rangle) a$ and $\nabla^2 f(x) = \psi''(\langle a, x \rangle) aa^T$.

Comment: $a$ is a degenerate point of $f$ if $Hessian(f(a))$ isn't invertible.

Comment: well, the hessian is at most rank 1.

Comment: but how can I construct the Hessian?  If $f(x)$ were something like $f(x,y) = x+y²sin(x) $ I could do it easily, but how to do it with something like $\langle a,x \rangle $?

Comment: Well $\langle a, x \rangle = a^T x$ is linear in $x$, so the derivative is the linear map itself, as Jacobian $a^T$ or as gradient $a$.

Comment: Then is it right to say: $ (a^{T}x)' = a^{T} $?

Comment: yiep ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets calculate the second derivatives in the case $n=2$, hopefully it get's more clear from there. First write $\langle a,x\rangle=a_1x_1+a_2x_2$. Then we have

$$f(x_1,x_2)=\psi(a_1x_1+a_2x_2) $$

Now it should be easy, we get

$$ \partial_{x_1}f(x_1,x_2)=\psi'(a_1x_1+a_2x_2)a_1 $$
$$ \partial_{x_2}f(x_1,x_2)=\psi'(a_1x_1+a_2x_2)a_2 $$

by using the chain rule. Taking this further we get

$$ Hessf(x_1,x_2)=\begin{pmatrix}
\psi''(a_1x_1+a_2x_2)a_1^2 & \psi''(a_1x_1+a_2x_2)a_1a_2 \\ 
\psi''(a_1x_1+a_2x_2)a_1a_2 & \psi''(a_1x_1+a_2x_2)a_2^2
\end{pmatrix}= \psi''(a_1x_1+a_2x_2)\begin{pmatrix}
a_1^2 & a_1a_2 \\ 
a_1a_2 & a_2^2
\end{pmatrix} $$

Now observe that the rows are multiples of each other, by multiplying the first row with $a_2$ and the second row with $a_1$. I leave it to you to generalize this to arbitrary dimensions. :)

Comment: Is it OK to assume $ \langle a,x \rangle $ is the euclidean inner product?

Comment: This should be OK, since an arbitrary inner product will have the form $\langle a,x \rangle=a^T A x$ for a suitable matrix $A$ (with certain conditions on $A$). Interpreting $a^TA=(A^Ta)^T=:b^T$ you have $\langle a,x \rangle=b_1x_1+b_2x_2$ and so this doesn't change much in your situation.